# Cannot change resolution on Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop with VMware tools

Tags: resolution, display, vmware

I installed a new linux guest in my VMWare Vsphere 5.1 enviroment.
This guest is a Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop.

Ater the installation of VMWare tools I wanted to change the resolution because now it is 800x600. I cannot change the resolution cause then the system hangs. Except changing it to 1024x768 it works. If I change it to a higher resolution it also hangs if i apply the resolution. VMWare tools should normally manage the resolution.. What is wrong here?

The display is displayed as "Unknown" under the display menu in Ubuntu.

Kr,

Answer (score 3):

Try typing in terminal: xrandr -s 1360x768 or whatever your resolution is.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it works.. why do the other resolutions don't work?

Comment: type in xrandr without any parameters and it will show you what are the possible resolutions for your device/system.

Answer (score 2):

I increased the assigned graphical memory of my VMWare guest to 8 MB and then it allowed me to select the higher resolutions. A lower setting for the GPU memory will restrict you to lower resolutions only.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had been trying everything but eventually tried the xrandr option - the command itself failed and I remembered this could be due to available memory. So I added memory (to 4GB) for the VM and the problem vanished.

I had had a lock-up and crash recently (which pops up as a cause on a similar question) so all I can only think is that the memory got reset and I had not noticed.